# How to read appsettings from CreateDbContext

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I implement **IDesignTimeDbContextFactory** to use EF migrations and I need to read appsettings.json file from **CreateDbContext** method.

The problem is that appsettings.json is located in another assembly.

```cs
public DataContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
{
    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>();

    var connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("Database:ConnectionString");

    builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, option =>
    {
        option.MigrationsAssembly("MyDbContextAssembly");
    });

    return new DataContext(builder.Options);
}
```

On this class, I need parameterless constructor and I can't inject IConfiguration.

How can resolve this issue?

Comment: Then build the configuration within the function

Comment: @Nkosi Do you mean use “new ConfigurationBuilder()”? I think that I can’t do this because appsettings is in another assembly

Comment: appsettings.json is a file that can be loaded. it is not embedded in an assembly. once you know the path you can load it.

Comment: @Nkosi but newConfiguration().SetBasePath(...) expects absolute path. I'ts correct reference bin folder from another assembly?

Answer (score 3):

Then build the configuration within the function. You can set the base path to where the settings should be loaded from

```
public DataContext CreateDbContext(string[] args) {    
    // Build config
    IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "../Relative path here"))
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();

    // Get connection string
    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>();
    var connectionString = configuration .GetConnectionString("Database:ConnectionString");
    builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, option =>
    {
        option.MigrationsAssembly("MyDbContextAssembly");
    });
    return new DataContext(builder.Options);
}
```

Found a helpful article [here](https://blog.tonysneed.com/2018/12/20/idesigntimedbcontextfactory-and-dependency-injection-a-love-story/) with even more customization.